# Update a crontab to tar new/updated files every 5 hours

Tags: ubuntu, cron

I'm trying to create a command for a crontab to tar every new/updated files (from when the cron last ran). The cron must run every 5 hours.

1. I want to backup all the files contained in the folder `/home/swayraines` including its subfolder
2. I want to save a tar with those files here `folder/backup/back.tar`
3. The crontab must run every **5 hours**
4. Only the files that have been **added or edited since the last time** the cron was executed need to be added to the archive. So unless it's new/edited it should not be saved.
5. I want to save the result in a log with both stdout and stderr here `folder/backup/backlog.log`

So I thought the best way to proceed is to `find` the files added/edited in the last 5 hours, and then `tar` those files, before outputing stdout and stderr in a .log but it's not working and i'm unsure what's wrong.

Here's what it looks like so far (updated to include partial answer):

```
  0 */5 * * * find /home/swayraines -mmin -300 -exec tar -zcvf folder/backup/back.tar {} > /folder/backup/backlog.log 2>&1 \;
```

**update**
The problem is that right now it creates a new tar archive every time the crontab runs, and the archive only contains the latest file added.

**update 2**
Just to be clear, I stated at first that I wanted to create a new archive every 5 hours, but rather I want to update the archive and append only the new files. So I believe I need to change the tar command to `-uvf` ?

Comment: Your current schedule will run every 5 hours until 20:00, then the next run after 4 hours. If you really want to enforce every 5 hours, you need a more elaborate schedule. But perhaps it would be simpler to just run every 4 hours or every 6 hours instead if keeping it steady is important.

Comment: That's a good suggestion. Will take that into account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use *signed* numbers for the argument. 300 means modified *exactly* 300 minutes ago. -300 is *less* than 300 minutes ago. +300 would be *more* than 300 minutes ago.

**UPDATE 1**

The argument to `-exec` must end with `\;`, like so:

```
 0 */5 * * * find /home/swayraines -mmin -300 -exec tar -zcvf folder/backup/back.tar {} > /folder/backup/backlog.log 2>&1 \;
```

This will run without a problem, but as it executes the command on 1 file at a time, you will wind up with only the last file that it operates on compressed into the *tar* file. I suggest you write the command to copy the files to a temporary directory, compress the temporary directory, and then remove the temporary directory.

**UPDATE 2**

Correct. You can use `-r --append` or `-u --update` if you want to append changed files to the end of the *tar* file, but the *tar* file will have to be created first. It will not create the file if it does not exist. It is important to note that these commands do not overwrite the previous version, therefore if you do not need both versions, you should use `--delete` first and then append the new version.

Also, note that this will not be a compressed *tar* file. You cannot update compressed *tar* files without un/re-compressing. That is why you cannot combine the `-z` and `-ur` options.

Comment: Oops that's correct. I've changed the value of -mmin but it's still not working. That was just a mistake on my part after changing the command so many times!

Comment: Good catch (again) while it does define adequately how far back I want to look for, it still doesn't work. I tried using the command as a simple command line, but the tar is not working.

Comment: My apologies for not checking out the full situation before answering. I just shared the first things that stood out. The answer has been updated with a full solution. As you were close already, I assume you can handle the commands for my final suggestion.

Comment: Thanks, that was actually very helpful and i've learned a lot!

Comment: Updated answer for part 3 of your question.